# Run Powershell Script in 32 bit mode

Tags: powershell, 32bit-64bit

I currently try to write a PowerShell Script, in which a I have to import a 32bit module. The script should be automatically started by the Windows Task Scheduler.
I wrote the following batch file, which starts the PowerShell script:

```
powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "\myFilePath\myScript.ps1"
exit 0
```

My problem is that the PS file now runs in the 64-bit version, because I am executing it in a 64 bit environment.

Can I "save" the script as 64-bit version or something like that?

Update:

I already tried `%windir%\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPo[...]` . This did not work for me. In my Error Log, which writes the script the typical error:

> The term 'New-RDBaseItem' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program.

Comment: @ Adam Luniewski Thank you for your help so far! Sorry for not informing you about this. I just updated my qustion. The missing backspace was just a typing error. It is correct in my code.

Comment: That error message just says that for whatever reason that cmdlet does not get imported. Run the script manually (with something like `$VerbosePreference = "Continue"`) to see what's actually going wrong. If this error appears with both 64-bit and 32-bit PowerShell, then bitness is obviously not the issue.

Comment: There may not be a 32 bit version of that module.

Answer (score 2):

Try to run it as a job like this:

```
$script = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
  powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "\myFilePath\myScript.ps1"
} -RunAs32
$script | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```